# Several HTML elements having same ID, is it so wrong?

Tags: css

In some DIV element, I have a complicated layout with different sub-elements having their own IDs. Today I realize I need to duplicate the whole thing and I have no time to recreate the same with different IDs.

Is it so bad to have two DIV with the same ID for example? What can happen?

Comment: I suggest you take the time to use classes properly. It will save you time in the future, as temporary solutions often become permanent temporary solutions.

Comment: Read This please http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that when selecting them using JS it's assumed that there will only be one of each ID – that means things typically break.

Specifically, `getElementById` is very fast, as it assumes only one of each id.

Additionally, the [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401) says:

> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique
>   in a document.

It's really not very hard to change, just swap `id` to `class`, and in your CSS `#` to `.`.

Comment: For further reading: [HTML5 specification's `ID attribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) and [HTML4 specification's `ID attribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id) (as quoted).

Answer (score 0):

An ID should be unique (only one element uses it), while class is more like universal (group of elements use it).

Quote from this [website](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php), think of it as a classroom:

> - ID = A person's Identification (ID) is unique to one person.
> - Class = There are many people in a class.

So, I suggest you change from ID to class.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad, really, since it should not be used like that.

Browsers are quite forgiving, but I would take the time to avoid this, using classes.